# Reexport class in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I have two classes in two files.

```
//a.ts
export class A{}

//b.ts
export class B{}
```

How I can build file `c.ts` from which I could import both classes?

```
import {A, B} from "c";
```

instead of

```
import {A} from "a";
import {B} from "b";
```

I want to make kind of export facade.
How to reexport type?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

I found answer by myself

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html @Re-exports

Code to do what I wanted

```
//c.ts
export {A} from "a";
export {B} from "b";
```

**Default export**

Assuming you have file

```
//d.ts
export default class D{}
```

Re-export have to look like this

```
//reexport.ts
export { default } from "d";
```

or

```
//reexport.ts
export { default as D } from "d";
```

What happens here is that you're saying "I want to re-export the `default export` of module "D" but with the name of `D`

Comment: and what if `A` and `B` are default (and not named) exports? 
`export A from 'a'` complains `declaration or statement required`

Comment: @dark_ruby you have to import and export on separate statements, updated answer

Answer (score 14):

For anyone not wanting to deal with default you re-export an imported
module like so

```
import {A} from './A.js';
import {B} from './B.js';

const C = 'some variable'

export {A, B, C}
```

This way you can export all the variables you either imported or declared in this file.

Taken from [here](https://typescript.programmingpedia.net/en/tutorial/9054/modules---exporting-and-importing#re-export)

Comment: If you don't need A/B in this file: `export { A } from './A'; export { B } from './B'; export const C = '...'`

Comment: @charles-allen Could you elaborate on your comment ?
I don't understand what you mean by "If you don't need...". Isn't the purpose of this example to show how to reexport them ? If you don't need them then you are just making an plain export

Comment: Just to be clear in case that's not obvious, you don't need to declare a third variable to export in your file. Your file can only import a bunch of types and reexport them all.

Comment: @cassepipe - It's possible to create a facade that re-exports things from multiple source modules without a separate import step (the 3 lines I posted above does the same as the 4 lines in the current solution by immediately reexporting).

Comment: If you also need to use A&B in the facade (ex: to create C) then you must import & export separately like you've done

Comment: @charles-allen I haven't done anything, tha'ts not my solution. Thanks very much for the clarification.