# TypeScript implement class after declare

Tags: typescript

I have a `types.ts` that defines all the types in my library:

```
interface Foo
{
  // ...
}

interface Bar
{
  // ...
}

declare class Baz
{
  // ...
}
```

As you can see, I'm using the `declare` keyword with my class `Baz` because I only want to define the type, not the implementation.

I then have a file `Baz.ts` which should define the implementation for `Baz`

```
class Baz
{
  // implementation here ...
}
```

How do I state that this `Baz` class is an implementation of the previously declared `Baz` type?

---

Also, this question should **not** turn into a discussion on whether one should separate interface and implementation or not.

---

**Edit**:

I cannot use `interface` for `Baz` because I only want one implementation as part of the library.

So I want to be able to do `import {Baz} from './types` and `new Baz()`.

Also `interface` is not a substitute because it doesn't allow `static` methods (which makes sense).

Comment: Why not separate interface and implementation?

Comment: I don't get why not make `interface Baz` and `class Whatever implements Baz`. Or just `import Baz`, I suppose.

Comment: @UweKeim I am .

Comment: @VLAZ I will edit question

Comment: `declare` describes existing JS code. You can't `declare` the class and then implement it, this does not work like in  C++

Comment: ...OK, with the edited question it seems even more that you just need to do `import Baz` and then `export Baz` in `types` and that's it. The files that import `types` won't actually care where `Baz` is coming from and you can swap the implementation at will.

Comment: @VLAZ TBH that makes a lot of sense, I just hope I can still declare the class inside `types` as well

Comment: @DavidCallanan I'm not sure what you mean by declaring it inside `types`. If it's imported, it's available within `types`. The `declare` keyword is used to just (essentially) say "This thing is defined but not here. Compiler, just trust me on this one and don't raise an error". But if you import and then export, you get what's called [a reexport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36790911/reexport-class-in-typescript) and it is often used to just collect a bunch of implementations from other files and provide them from a single one and to allow flexibility to changing them later.

Comment: @VLAZ this would allow me separate declaration and implementation, preventing me from accidentally making breaking changes when updating the implementation

Comment: @VLAZ It looks like this solution might have a problem (but I'll have to wait and see when my code is finished): if `types` imports `Baz`, and `Baz` imports `types` then there is infinite loop.